# Interpreting standardized coefficients on a natural log response variable in OLS multiple regression

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, interpretation

I am working on a housing problem in which I use dichotomous and ratio data to predict
housing production (units constructed in a year-ratio) in a 17 year time period. At this time, I am using OLS and as I get better at stats, I shall attempt this problem using time-series analysis.  That said, I have used R to standardize all of my ratio predicting data and left the dichotomous data raw.  And I have also transformed the response variable to a Natural log to normalize the distribution (i.e. many, many zeros>>yes, I know Poisson or Zero-populated counts in the future).

I have read the post on "interpret coefficients from a quantile regression on standardized data" and also the "convert my unstandardized independent variables to standardized." Based on those, I think that can do the following interpretation based on the following output. The variable `region_id` is dichotomous, `supply` is standardized.

```
Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          2.687e+00  2.171e-01  12.379  < 2e-16 ***

region_id            1.805e+00  1.383e-01  13.049  < 2e-16 ***

supply              -2.205e+01  2.204e+00 -10.005  < 2e-16 ***
```

Region Interpretation:
For every on city that is located in the Houston region, you can expect that annual housing production will increase by 1.8%.

Supply Interpretation:
For every one-unit increase in the standard deviation of housing supply, you can expect that annual housing production will decrease by -22.05%.

Nota bene.
I am not a stats or math person at all,
but I have been using R for the past three years
and I am quite familiar with OLS, but if you throw
up an equation it will look "appropriately" Greek to me. :)

Comment: Do you mean you're using the model $\log Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 z_i + \epsilon_i$?  (where $x_i$ is either 0 or 1)  If so your estimated coefficients seem extremely large.

Comment: @rje42, they are extremely large due to the range in the sample. However, region data is not standardized. It is simply 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

For binary predictors with large coefficients, the effect of region going from 0 to 1 is $100 \cdot(\exp\{\beta\}-1),$ which means the effect if more like 536% for Houston. When coefficients are small, this transformation will give you roughly the same result as merely looking at them. The intuition is that for a model like $E[y|D]=\exp\{\alpha + \beta D\}\cdot E[\exp{u}],$ where the second term comes from the retransformation back to levels from logs, the effect of D is \begin{equation}\ln
\frac{E[y|D=1]-E[y|D=0]}{E[Y|D=0)} \cdot 100=\frac{\exp\{\alpha + \beta\}-\exp\{\alpha\}}{\exp\{\alpha\}} \cdot 100=(\exp\{\beta\}-1) \cdot 100
\end{equation}

Unfortunately, you can't just plug $\hat \beta$ in for $\beta$. You want to use $$100 \cdot \exp \left( \hat \beta - \frac{1}{2} \hat \sigma_{\beta}^2 \right), $$

where $\hat \sigma_{\beta}$ is the standard error of that coefficient. Similarly, I think you want to multiply the supply coefficient by 100 as well.

These estimates do seem very large, but I really don't know what to expect here.

Take a look at [this post](http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/03/dummies-for-dummies.html) by David Giles for formulas and sources. The bias correction he describes (as long as you are willing to assume the errors are normal) will take your effect down a bit, but not substantively so.

Comment: @dimitry, The estimates are large. It is because the sample includes cities as large as Houston (pop 2 million) to Pasadena TX with a (pop 141K), therefore Houston acts as a huge leverage  and outlier and the data display this wide range.  This is my first test of this data.  ON MY NEXT go round, I plan to sample cities that are within 1 std dev in population and therefore the estimates will be more meaningful.

Comment: I wonder if you can accomplish this by including a $\ln (pop)$ with the constraint that its coefficient equals $1$. This assumes that housing production is proportional to population: $\frac{E[y \vert x]}{pop}=\exp\{x'\beta\},$ which is algebraically equivalent to a model where $E[y \vert x]=\exp\{x'\beta+\ln {pop}\}$. The term for this is a logarithmic offset.