# How Can I Interpretation in loglinear regressions with coefficients greater than 1

Tags: regression, panel-data, stata, log-linear

I run a loglinear regression and got dummy variable coefficient for education level bigger than one. It's also significant and my depend variable's log wage.
How would I go about to interpret the 2.21?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check if this post does not answer your question [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61453/interpretation-in-log-linear-regressions-with-coefficients-bigger-than-1?rq=1). Otherwise revise the question so it is clear how your question is different.

Comment: Another answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43683/7071).